# error: cannot find symbol в калькуляторе на java

Tags: java, калькулятор

```
public class Calculate 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int num1 = Integer.valueOf(arg[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.valueOf(arg[2]);

        if (arg[1].equals("+")) 
        {
            int res = num1 + num2;
        }

        if (arg[1].equals("-"))
        {
            int res = num1 - num2;
        }

        if (arg[1].equals("*"))
        {
            int res = num1 * num2;
        }

        if (arg[1].equals("/"))
        {
            int res = num1 / num2;
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в области видимости переменной `res`.

Переменная, объявленная в каком-либо блоке кода, видна только в этом же блоке кода (и во всех вложенных) **и не видна извне**.

Объявите переменную `res` следующим образом:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    int res = 0;

    /// ...

}
```

В этом случае, Вы сможете обратиться к переменной `res` в любом месте в пределах метода `main(...)`.

Обратите внимание, что возможна ситуация, когда ни один из блоков `if` не выполнится и переменная `res` не будет инициализирована и вывести ее на консоль не получится. Для этого я изначально инициализировал эту переменную (этот случай можно обрабатывать по-разному).

PS. Разумеется, при этом необходимо из всех остальных блоков убрать объявление этой переменной.

PPS. Все эти `if` можно заменить на `switch-case` (JDK 7+).